# Fue dibujado / se dibujó por

Tags: gramática

Me pregunto si esos opciones son intercambiables. Ayúdeme aprenderlo.

> Ese gato se dibujó por la señorita Elisabeth.

> Ese gato fue dibujado por la señorita Elisabeth.

Comment: debujar o dibujar?

Comment: Un gato no se puede dibujar. Es un verbo transitivo y el pasivo es: Ese gato fue dibujado por la señorita Elisabeth.

Comment: Quiere decir que la señorita dibujó un gato en una hoja de papel. ¿Por qué no se puede dibujar un gato así?

Comment: @Lambie Un gato sí se puede dibujar, como también se lo puede imaginar, soñar, pintar, delinear, etc.

Comment: @Gustavson Un gato se puede dibujar por una persona. Pero no sin la persona.

Comment: @Lambie Cuando se dice "por una persona", necesariamente debe usarse la pasiva con "ser": Un gato puede ser dibujado por una persona. La pasiva con "se" no admite el agente, por ejemplo: Se puede pintar un paisaje PERO Un paisaje puede ser pintado por un artista.

Comment: Exacto por eso no se dice: El gato se dibujo. La chica dibujó el gato. Se dibujo un gato en la pared para la fiesta. se dibujo esquivale a: Un gato fue dibujado por x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La pasiva con "se" (*Se dibujó ese gato*) generalmente suena mejor si el verbo se antepone al sujeto y requiere que NO se mencione al agente (en este caso, "la señorita Elisabeth").

Si se menciona el agente, DEBE usarse la pasiva llamada perifrástica, formada por el verbo "ser" y el participio del verbo principal (en este caso, "dibujado").

Las únicas opciones de pasiva en este caso son:

- Se dibujó ese gato / Ese gato se dibujó. (Alguien no mencionado lo dibujó)
- Ese gato fue dibujado. (Alguien no mencionado lo dibujó)
- Ese gato fue dibujado por la señorita Elisabeth.